# Wrong counts for refiner values in SharePoint 2013, Enterprise Search Center

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, refinement-panel, refiner

I followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/searchguys/archive/2012/08/16/getting-refiner-counts-back-in-sharepoint-2013-search.aspx) to enable counts on SharePoint 2013 on a Enterprise Search Center site.

Counts are displayed but they are not accurate.

For example, for refiner "Languages" with "en" value it shows 29 documents but when I refine by "en" it shows 53 documents.

Any ideas why is this happening? Is this a SharePoint bug ?

See this image:

[image: wrong counts]

Comment: Any luck with correcting the counts?  Was the solution to run a full crawl as suggested by DrFeelgood?

Comment: No, we implemented our own web part to correct this, requesting refiners using REST api will give the right counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but just in case anyone else stumbles across this I found a property in the refiner web part that was the culprit. Now I will caveat this with saying I am currently working on SharePoint 2016, but the refiner control and code doesn't appear to have been changed since SP13.

We are working with a large dataset (1.7 million records) and when the results were still in hudreds of thousand, the refiners were off. When searching and refining the results so that they were at a smaller count (< 100,000) the refiners were playing nice, which got me thinking.

So I exported the Refiner web part and under the "**SelectedRefinementControlsJson**" property, for each refiner added, there was a "**deepHits**" attribute set at 100000 (100,000). As soon as I made higher, or in my case I added a zero to maek it 1000000 (1,000,000), the results started returning correctly. Even at for refiners over 1,000,000 mark they now show correctly.

**Before Fix**

[image: Before Fix]

**After Fix**

[image: After Fix]

Comment: Nice! That does the trick and explains a lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

When was the last time you ran a full crawl since this issue? I'll be clear, I don't think that's the issue but managed properties (the refiners) are very unique and a full crawl is needed before you can even search against them. I wouldn't be half-surprised, as unbelievable as it sounds, that you would need to do a full crawl for the refiners to show the correct amounts. Perhaps that's why Microsoft doesn't show them by default. The managed properties may only be pulling items from the last full crawl index.

Aside from that, could you post your search display template that shows the number as well as let us know what types of searches you are running?

Answer (score -2):

Are you using FAST Search?

If you aren't then I am pretty sure the numbers are actually estimated.  This is due to the fact that the refinement panel doesn't look at the whole set of results to get the counts.

I encountered the same problem when setting up a refinment panel and ultimately decided not to use the counts due to the inaccuracy, if someone knows of another solution i'd love to know as well.

Comment: It is Enterprise Search Center

Comment: Isn't FAST supposed to be the default search engine for SP2013?

Comment: I didn't realize it was 2013 when I posted this... my fault.

Comment: No problem, easy to miss. And for the record, it was not me that downvoted you